# WooCommerce: hiding payment buttons until shipping is selected

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been contacted by a client for whom I made a website a few years ago. It was before I made custom themes from scratch, so it's a bit of a hot mess of a template/child theme.

The client wants the bottom of the checkout section to only display once the user has progressed past choosing their shipping, otherwise users are able to just click through to the last stage of the checkout process without choosing shipping. As far as I can see, no classes are changed on any containing divs from one view of the checkout to another, so I can't find anything to target with CSS that will hide this section until the user is on the correct view. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can achieve this?

The site is here: http://www.hidalgoequine.com

Much appreciated!

Comment: trying to do it with css doesn't seem like the correct approach. You should make the shipping fields required, that way users can't click on the next step because they have to fill out the shipping first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As far as I can see the shipping is set to required, but the problem is that the payment method/'place order' div is visible at all stages of the checkout process, so a user can click to go to the WorldPay checkout before even adding their address. I'm against hacks but this client isn't paying for this work (they see it as a fault with the original website) so I'm looking for any functional solution.

Answer (score 0):

add your custom "previous" and "next" button in Theme overriding for woocomerce check out page (or) Using Jquery, add your custom buttons and attach events - based on that show / hide. example to hide shipping. jQuery(".six.columns.shipping").hide(); Based on the CSS active / track the step count and display the div accordingly. And last step once showing the payment option, then display the paynow button.

Comment: Thanks Senthil. Not sure I'm completely understanding your answer, but I'll try a jQuery hack based on the state of the unordered list with the checkout steps, (the li of the active view has a class of 'active') and I'll post  the solution here if I get that working.